# How can I take advantage of meeting myself?

Tags: millennia-altered-destinies

In [Millennia Altered Destinies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millennia:_Altered_Destinies) it's possible to run into an alternate version of yourself. When communicating with the other you's vessel, it's possible to transmit a numeric code. I've played this game many times but have never been able to figure out what to do in this situation.

The developers of the game (Take 2 Interactive) have this to say about the situation:

> You are in the fifth dimension. An anomaly of time travel is that on rare
>   occasions, you will actually meet another version of yourself that is traveling
>   from another time, outside the material plane. When you encounter this
>   phenomenon you can use it to your advantage, if you are very clever. There is
>   some information that we can't bring ourselves to divulge to anyone.

I'm hoping to be very clever by asking this question here and getting the answer that way, not knowing what to do here has been bugging me for the past 15 years.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When meeting yourself for the first time, your alternate self will ask you who you are. Respond by saying I am you. After this you will be able to enter a number.

When encountering yourself again ask yourself who you are, and your other self will respond with "I am you". Then enter the numbers you originally communicated to yourself.

Go to the teleportation screen, it's now possible to receive a special weapon trough transport from yourself; the Microid diffusion weapon.

Source: series of youtube movies, in particular [this one.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5io8w-WHrrY&feature=relmfu)

Answer (score 7):

I don't know that we'll ever know, seeing as the secret has been part of the game for 15 years and nobody's quite figure it out yet.  Having said that, my best guess is that it has something to do with [this](http://dlh.net/chtdb/chtview.php?lang=eng&sys=pc&disp=e3189):

> What does it mean when I have done nothing to effect time and all of
>   the sudden a temporal storm happens.?
>
> This is an indication that an alternative version of yourself, one
>   that has been sent in to assist the microids, has done something to
>   effect the timeline of one of your friendly species.  He is your
>   alter-ego.

What I take from this is that events in another game you've played can effect the game you're currently playing.  In this case, it's likely helpful if you can remember what you did in that game, so you can predict the effects in your current game.  I'd imagine this transmission you can make to yourself is intended for this purpose.  You could use it to determine *which other game* is impacting *your current game*.

Since it's not always possible to achieve success in the game, due to the fact that the two goals are frequently divergent, having two chances in the same universe might make it possible to do both, but this is mostly just speculation on my part.

Comment: Wow that's cool. I need to check out this game!

Comment: That's an interesting notion agent86, definitely worth checking out. The alternate version they're talking about is actually an alter ego of yourself from a parallel universe assisting the enemy. The person you run into in the fifth dimension is an alter ego also trying to help the 4 alien races. But having one game influencing another game is something I could see the creators of Millennia actually doing.